# How to get part of line from txt file in android app

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader, readline

I have a .txt file,  and I managed to create app which can read this txt file and get the text from it to a string,

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        // i have kept text.txt in the sd-card

        if(file.exists())   // check if file exist
        {
            //Read text from file
            StringBuilder textt = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if(line.startsWith("[A]")){
                        textt.append(line);
                        textt.append('n');

                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            }
            //Set the text
            text.setText(textt);
        }
        else
        {
            text.setText("Sorry file doesn't exist!!");
        }
```

And my txt file is

```
What is the biggest county in the world.......
[A]China.     [B]Usa.         [C]Russia.   [D]France

What is the tallest river in the world.........
[A]Nile.     [B]Mesesbie.         [C]khan.   [D]Red river

.........
```

As you can see, my text file contains some questions and four answers for every question  , and I want to make my app get the questions in arrylist,  and the **[A]** answers in arrylist , and the **[B]** answers in array list,  ( the same with C and D)  .

```
public ArrayList<String> Questions=new ArrayList<>();                               
    public ArrayList<String> answerA=new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> answerB=new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> answerC=new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> answerD=new ArrayList<>();
```

But I don't know how to do this  , I read about (split)  and (substring) and tried to get the **[A]** answers,  but I couldn't , because my app gave me every line start with [A] and I want the answer of [A] without [B] or [C] or other answers ,

so if some one have a good solution for me,  I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine readLines to form a single string, instead tackle each line separately.

There can be many scenario in this case:

-Question over single or multiple lines

if a line does not contain any of these [A] and [B] and [C] and [D], its a question line and all lines after that matching this criteria until next occurrence of [A] or [B] or [C] or [D] in it are question and should be placed in questions ArrayList

-Each option of Answer in a single line

> [A]option1 [B]option2 [C]option3 [D]option4

if a line contains all of these [A] and [B] and [C] and [D],
determine positions of [A] and [B] and [C] and [D] in the string of readLine and place parts between those positions in corresponding array.

-Each option of Answer on separate lines

> [A]option1
>
> [B]option2
>
> [C]option3
>
> [D]option4

this condition can be true, when only one of [A] or [B] or [C] or [D] is present , while rest are missing. in that case ,add this line to its corresponding ArrayList()

-some option in one line, others separate

> [A]option1 [B]option2 [C]option3
>
> [D]option4

I hope you got the idea of what needs to be done!!